# How to pass parameters to build selects in collection of embedded forms in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Please, I need some advice on Symfony forms and entities.
I have Questionarie(entity) form with number of assigned Rows(entities). Rows objects are assigned to Questionarie object. Each row has select input with options from DB. Options are entities, let's say OptionEntity. Each select is filled with query for OptionEntities based on one parameter.

Each Row stores chosen answer. Each answer is assigned to question. Row knows nothing about question.

So I build a QuestionarieType form with some fields and collection of embedded RowType forms.

The question is how to pass parameters to queries to build options in each row. As Rows objects are assigned to Questionarie object all rows in form are built automatically. So I don't know how map parameters to corresponding rows.

I think about additional field in Row entity to store this paramater but I don't know whether it is bad idea because Row entity is used to store chosen answer and knows nothing about question.

Thank you! Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
Controller action:
{
        $questionarie = new Questionarie(); // just a wrapper for questions with some meta data: userId, timestamp, etc.
        /*here I fetch questions from DB somehow and then iterate through them:*/
        foreach ($question as $q) {
            $row = new FormRow();
            $questionarie->addFormRow($row);
        }
    $form = $this->createForm(QuestionarieType::class, $questionarie);
}

class QuestionarieType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('FormRows', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => FormRowType::class,
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Sfedu\RatingBundle\Entity\Questionarie',
        ));
    }
}

class FormRowsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'SfeduRatingBundle:Answer',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($question_id){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->where('a.question = :question')
                        ->setParameter('question', $question_id); //! here I want to use parameter to filter possible answers for each row
                },
             ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at CollectionType and DataTransformers. Basically one Row will be a dedicated form type mapped by CollectionType.

Comment: @mblaettermann Would you mind providing a little more information? I have read about data transformers, but can't understand how to use them to pass paramaters to each collection item. Please look at the UPD, I provided some code there.

Comment: `FormBuilderInterface` (through `FormConfigInterface`) has `FormBuilderInterface::getData()`, which would return (in your case) `$questionarie` from the controller action. Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @Yoshi What I want is to pass **different** $question_id for each Row. I don't know how to do this even if I get $questionarie in my FormRowsType.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, each `Row` represents the answer to a question defined by the option-select? If so, I think you could help yourself a lot if you'd just make the question available to `Row`. Specifically in regards do *"...because Row entity is used to store chosen answer and knows nothing about question."* Why wouldn't/shouldn't the answer be coupled to the question?

Comment: @Yoshi each Row is the answer to particular question. The Row stores only the answer, not a question. Set of possible answers (select options) for each Row is defined by question.
So Row is assigned to chosen Answer (select option) and Answer is assigned to Question. I wonder if it is a bad practice to add straight relation from Row to Question - it will denormalize model. Probably I confuse model and database..

Comment: @Yoshi ok, so I should add the question to the Row and get the Row object in RowType using the getData()?

Comment: I guess so. Honestly I still have some problems imagining your data-model, but it feels as if the answer should be coupled to the question directly, probably in some *container* entity (possibly `Row`), that is coupled to the Questionarie (in relation to the answerer maybe?). And I think from there it's just a short step to having the required data in your form builder.